# How to refactor Rails 'params' method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, refactoring, ruby-on-rails-5

Hello there is simple pattern to deal with params security but it makes a lot of mess in Controller Can i do anything with it ?

```
def report_params
  params.require(:report).permit(
    :example_field_1,
    :example_field_2,
    :example_field_3,
    :example_field_4,
    :example_field_5,
    :example_field_6,
    :example_field_7,
    :example_field_8,
    :example_field_9,
    :example_field_10,
    :example_field_11,
    :example_field_12,
    :example_field_13,
    :example_field_14,
    :example_field_15,
    :example_field_16,
    :example_field_17,
    :example_field_18,
    :example_field_19,
    :example_field_20,
    :example_field_21,
    :example_field_22,
    :example_field_23,
    :example_field_24,
    :example_field_25,
    :example_field_26,
    :example_field_27,
    :example_field_28,
    :example_field_29,
    :example_field_30,
    :example_field_31,
    :example_field_32,
    :example_field_33,
    :example_field_34,
    :example_field_35,
    :example_field_36,
    :example_field_37,
    :example_field_38,
    :example_field_39,
    :example_field_40,
    :example_field_41,
    :example_field_42,
    :example_field_43,
    :example_field_44,
    :example_field_45,
    :example_field_46,
    :example_field_47,
    :example_field_48,
    example_address_1_attributes: Address::PUBLIC_ATTRIBUTES,
    example_address_2_attributes: Address::PUBLIC_ATTRIBUTES,
    documents_attributes: Document::PUBLIC_ATTRIBUTES
  )
end
```

I made some refactor by specifying shared attributes inside of models. I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: I read a nice [blog post](https://edelpero.svbtle.com/strong-parameters-the-right-way) on this a while back. It's a bit dated (based on Rails 4) but I think still relevant.

Comment: @moveson This is exactly what I was looking for thank you :). Project is on Rails 4 :).

Answer (score 3):

How about something like:

```
def report_params
  allowed = (1..48).map{|i| "example_field_#{i}".to_sym}
  params.require(:report).permit(
    allowed,
    example_address_1_attributes: Address::PUBLIC_ATTRIBUTES,
    example_address_2_attributes: Address::PUBLIC_ATTRIBUTES,
    documents_attributes: Document::PUBLIC_ATTRIBUTES
  )
end
```

If I do this in console:

```
> allowed = (1..48).map{|i| "example_field_#{i}".to_sym}
 => [:example_field_1, :example_field_2, :example_field_3, :example_field_4, :example_field_5, :example_field_6, :example_field_7, :example_field_8, :example_field_9, :example_field_10, :example_field_11, :example_field_12, :example_field_13, :example_field_14, :example_field_15, :example_field_16, :example_field_17, :example_field_18, :example_field_19, :example_field_20, :example_field_21, :example_field_22, :example_field_23, :example_field_24, :example_field_25, :example_field_26, :example_field_27, :example_field_28, :example_field_29, :example_field_30, :example_field_31, :example_field_32, :example_field_33, :example_field_34, :example_field_35, :example_field_36, :example_field_37, :example_field_38, :example_field_39, :example_field_40, :example_field_41, :example_field_42, :example_field_43, :example_field_44, :example_field_45, :example_field_46, :example_field_47, :example_field_48] 

> p = ActionController::Parameters.new(report: {example_field_12: 'foo', bogus: 'field', good: 'extra'})
 => {"report"=>{"example_field_12"=>"foo", "bogus"=>"field", "good"=>"extra"}}

> p.require(:report).permit(allowed, :good)
Unpermitted parameter: bogus
 => {"example_field_12"=>"foo", "good"=>"extra"}
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't clear but I used 'example_field_' pattern only for purpose, normally those are different names. Your approach gives me a good idea, I will use sorted list ` %[…]`.

Answer (score 1):

Moveson placed [link to a great blog post](https://edelpero.svbtle.com/strong-parameters-the-right-way). I used that approach. It is very useful I don't need to keep shared attributes in models and controllers looks much better ;) !